# ServiceStack hello world example not generating soap proxies

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack

I just updated my references to the new ServiceStack from nuget (from 3.9.11 to version 3.9.56) and I could not get my soap clients to work. So I decided to try once again the Hello World solution provided on [github] (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Hello) which by the way is using an older version (3.9.32).

I added the `[DataContract]` attributes on the `Hello` and `HelloResponse` classes and then I tried to build a C# console client by adding a service reference to my localhost soap12 endpoint (using the Add Service Reference on VS2010, also tried 2012 and 2013). Unfortunately while I do get the `OneWayClient` and the `SyncReplyClient` I do not get any of my DTOs generated. Why is that? I tried to build my code with an older version of ServiceStack (using the `IService<T>` and the `Execute` method and everything worked fine! Are there any breaking changes that I am not aware of?

P.S. I tried also to recompile the whole ServiceStack.Examples project against the nuget libraries and it failed too. I could not even generate the proxy. Please do not try to convince me to use a share assembly for my DTOs as this defeats the purpose of having a language agnostic web service!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally solved the issue so I am going to post the answer here. ServiceStack is not as broken as it seems although all the examples on the github repo need an update to work with the latest version. So to the point: if you want your classes to correctly produce proxy classes you have to decorate them all not only with the `[DataContract]` attribute on the class level but also with the `[DataMember]` on the property level i.e.

```
[DataContract]
class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Of course you also need to either specify the namespace on the `[DataContract]` attribute (for Mono compatibility) or you will have to add a few lines on the AssemblyInfo.cs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937435/visual-studio-referencing-a-servicestack-soap-method).

Be warned though! All your DTOs including request types and response types should be on the same namespace! Also if you define only first level classes as request types (like the User example I used) then you will **not** get a proxy class! Instead all the public members will become method parameters. If you had though, by composition, another public member within User class i.e.

```
[DataContract]
class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public MyClass MyMember { get; set; }
}
```

then you would get your proxies for the MyClass though not for User. As for response types better read the [ServiceStack wiki on SOAP limitations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#soap-limitations).

Last note: I usually have strong opinions only about flexibility, simplicity, finding alternatives and making things work. I find pointless the discussions that try to support a language over another, an architecture over another, a buzzword/niche technology over a standard approach, using tools that make life easier over hardcoding everything. So I see as such the discussion on the comments above and I wish to continue no more.

I am just glad that a great tool like ServiceStack continues to provide what most users use it for: **A variety of alternatives.**

Answer (score 3):

> Please do not try to convince me to use a share assembly for my DTOs as this defeats the purpose of having a language agnostic web service!

Doesn't sound like a Getting things done attitude. Not sure what you think the purpose of a service is but it's not to implement the complex WS-* specification (which is dead), it's not even to appease some proprietary code-gen proxy tool, especially ones that generates RPC method signatures coupling code-gen types to generate proxy clients that's limited to using the inefficient and bloated SOAP format which provides what is arguably the [most fragile combination of technologies used in web service implementations](http://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack) today.

The purpose of a service is actually... just to provide a service - to encapsulate some capability and make it available remotely, in the most accessible, tolerant and interoperable way possible, ideally efficiently with the least amount of effort, friction and complexity.

Not sure why you think SOAP generated proxies is the ticket to having a language agnostic web service? Given that code-gen proxy implementations are often weak, incomplete and deprecated on platforms that aren't popular within Enterprises.

The whole purpose of a WSDL was to provide some machine readable spec which code-gen proxies can use to generate a typed service client - that's the purpose of a WSDL (not a service) - a tool to serve a means to an end (to provide connectivity to a service). But under all that complexity and closed-source black-box tooling it's still unable to re-create the clean DTO types that are developed and maintained on the server. But you can avoid all that artificial machinery and complexity by just copying the .dll (or source code) to your .NET client projects, giving you symmetrical parity with the Server DTOs that lets you use any of ServiceStack's [generic .NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#built-in-clients) providing the ability to re-use the same DTO's in any supported format (even built-in WCF/SOAP Clients) since the generic typed clients are substitutable.

WS-*/SOAP is deprecated because it was un-necessarily complex, it was built on the false premise that to provide an "interoperable service" you need to be abstract, explicit and opt-in to complexity. The opposite is true, you get much better interoperability, with less effort and friction using a simpler format and simple URIs, which is why new Web APIs today wont support SOAP.

Comment: I made this last note just because I wanted to avoid such a debate as I don't consider stackoverflow the place for such debates. I don't completely disagree with your approach (auto generated proxies do suck sometimes) but you seem to forget that people use tools to become more productive and that maybe I want a Java or C++ client for my service! Why should I implement once again the DTOs? That's the language agnostic part! I don't care about having only C# clients. So you just defeated your own saying: "ideally efficiently with the least amount of effort, friction and complexity."

Comment: And let me tell you that the biggest financial Firms in the world (it happens that I work in one of them) have a ton of infrastructure based on wsdls and proxies. It is just the simplicity of the implementation. It's the real "getting things done" approach.
But anyway, can I have an answer to my question? You are saying that Servicestack will no longer give a way to generate proxies via the soap endpoint?

Comment: Your last note was counter-intuitive, opinionated and in need of correcting, and you're also confusing [Simplicity with Ease of use](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy). It's not **Getting Things Done** if you're avoiding the recommended approach that works based on misplaced ideological belief you have about services. Dynamic languages doesn't need to generate types it's easier to parse raw JSON dynamically than trying to work with SOAP and you can code-gen types for static langs with Protocol Buffers or even using a XSD-like utility consumed with a normal HTTP Client.

Comment: It is funny though how you refuse to just answer. I don't ask for the alternatives (I know them already and I have rejected them as did a whole bunch of people out there). Can I get that xsd/wsdl like behavior from your API or not? Cause it seems broken. The "recommended approach" according to who? Do I have to remind you that this is the approach your own API was supporting until a couple of months ago? **Easier** for clients having to manually discover my DTOs or having to parse a pile of protobuf files instead of just giving a link on a tool? Who's opinionated and confused now?

Comment: I no longer [investigate individual support issues](http://tinyurl.com/oss-support), I've just answered here to correct poor information streams so others aren't misled into the same cult thinking. It's "ServiceStack's Recommended Approach", i.e. exactly what is was built to solve. But if you think it's wrong and Enterprise tools have it easy - use an enterprise product. Dealing with types is simpler because you can easily debug interoperability issues like this without being at the mercy of the opinions contained in some black-box tooling. I may have strong opinions, but I'm not confused...

Comment: ... With that said, I've just tried created a Hello World app with the latest NuGet and the generated still proxy works. Make sure you adhere to the guidelines in the [SOAP Limitations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#soap-limitations). Some [recent WSDL improvements](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/7dfeb71450bf5bd0982fce5f8c1c52ec6d936bbb) were just added so there may be less issues using binaries built from the master repo.